# Using iFrame in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, grails, iframe

I have two different html pages. I want to display the second one into the first one using iframe. Both the html pages are in my grail-app folder under assets/templates/mainapp/.
I am using ngroute for the pages.

The first **html** page is

```
    <!-- @author Karan Shah -->
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Document Display Contents</h1>

        <!-- Back -->
        <a href="#/documents">Back to the List of Documents</a>

        <!-- Get the name of the selected document from previous view to be displayed on current view  -->
        <br>    
        <div ng-controller='displaycontrol'>
            You are viewing : <b>{{doc}}</b>
        </div>

        <!-- Http get request to get the text of the document to controller -->
        <br>    
        <div ng-controller='textcontrol'>
            {{textofdocument}}
        </div>

        <div>
            <iframe ng-src="/maindocument.html">Fail</iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The second **HTML** page is (maindocument.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello how are you ??
</body>
</html>
```

The **controller file**

```
/**
 * @author Karan Shah
 * 
 */

var documentDisplayModule = angular.module('ald.documentdisplay',[]);

// Selected document name from previous view gets displayed on the document display view using $routeParams
documentDisplayModule.controller('displaycontrol',['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.doc=$routeParams.doc;
}]);

// $http.get to get the text based on the selected document
documentDisplayModule.controller('textcontrol',['$scope','$http','$routeParams',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
    $http.get("/document/getContents?docName="+$routeParams.doc).success(function(datatext){
    $scope.textofdocument=datatext;
    })
}])

documentDisplayModule.controller('framecontrol',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.docurl="assets/templates/mainapp/maindocument.html";
}])
```

I think I am not getting the src right. Can someone tell me what should the source be? I am not able to display anything. This is the **error** that i am getting when debugging:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/maindocument.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: is maindocument.html in the same folder as the other html page?

Comment: yes its in the same folder

Comment: Why do you think the src is not right? What error are you getting?

Comment: I think it should work since all the html pages are in the same folder. However I am getting the error of HTTP Status 404 - /maindocument.html

Answer (score 1):

The source should be where your maindocument.html is located in your folder

ie.

assets/templates/mainapp/maindocument.html

use -

```
<iframe src="assets/templates/mainapp/maindocument.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: if its in the same folder as the other html then shouldn't src="maindocuemnt.html" work ?

Comment: yes it should. Check the maindocument.html is a valid html page with the correct html tags

Comment: Well the error is gone but it does not display what it is supposed to.

Comment: doesnt display anything..this is the html sampel 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello how are you ??
</body>
</html>